# printing the address of the array using "array name" and "address-of array name"

Tags: c, arrays, arraylist, operators, logical-operators

someone please explain the output of the following code..

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int arr[5];
        // Assume base address of arr is 2000 and size of integer is 32 bit
        printf("%u %u", arr + 1, &arr + 1);         
        return 0;
    }
```

also explain the out when the "printf" statement is replaced by following

```
1. printf("%u %u", arr + 1, &(arr + 1));
2. printf("%u %u", arr + 1, &arr + 2);
```

Comment: What output were you expecting?

Comment: Also you should use %p to print addresses.

Comment: The address of an array (`&arr`) and the address of an array's first element (`&arr[0]` - what you get when `arr` decays to a pointer) have the same numerical value but do not mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is better to use format specifier `%p` that is specially designed for pointers instead of format specifier `%u`

In this statement

```
printf("%u %u", arr + 1, &arr + 1);
```

in expression `arr + 1` array `arr` is converted to pointer to its first element. So it has type after conversion `int *` and correspondingly the element it points to has type `int`. Due to the pointer arithmetic expression `arr + 1` will point to the next element of the array that is to the second element. So the value of pointer `arr`+ 1`is greater than the value of pointer`arr`by`sizeof( int )`

In this expression `&arr + 1` pointer `&arr` has type `int ( * )[5]` . The element it points to (that is array `arr`) has type `int[5]` . So the value of expression `&arr + 1` greater than the value of `&arr` by `sizeof( int[5] )`

As for expression `&(arr + 1)` then it will not compile because `arr + 1` is a temporary object and you may not take the address of a temporary object.

Comment: Just to make it complete: "`arr + 1` is a temporary object".. and not a `lvalue`...

Answer (score 0):

Output of 1st `printf` will be(According to assumption you specified) -`2032 2160`

as `arr+1` points to next element that is arr[1] and `&arr+1` in this `arr` is a int(*)[5] points to int[5] thus `address of arr that is base address` plus size of int[5] (here in your case 5*32).

In your second `printf` `&(arr+1)` is not lvalue thus does not occupy some identifiable location in memory.Thus will give an error.

Thrid `printf` will give output as `2032 2320`.Can be evaluated as done in 1st `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

The output of above code is 2004  2020.

The value arr and &arr yield to same result as the array is uninitialized it will print the value of address on place of its value.

This is due of the fact bcz when u print (arr+1) ,it adds the size of arraytype i.e int (4byte) to result

But when u do ( &(arr+1)) ,it will adds the size of whole array i.e (5*4=20 bytes )to  base address.

When u print &(arr+1) it will produce error bcz it will now treat & as unary& not as addressing operator

Comment: Vishesh please see the size of integer he specified in his question. And it is not necessary that size of integer is always 4 bytes .

Comment: Amey  u r right abt size of integer is not always 4 byte .it varies with ur bit version of OS.  I give my answer in byte form as he don't mention abt the value of 2000 in bit/byte